# "For" command and "findstr" in windows command prompt

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, dos, findstr

In a different post, i found this solution to rename a file to the current date in the ISO-format:

```
FOR /F %%A IN ('WMIC OS GET LocalDateTime ^| FINDSTR \.') DO @SET B=%%A
copy test.java %B:~0,4%-%B:~4,2%-%B:~6,2%.java
```

I understand everything except this part:

```
 ^| FINDSTR \.
```

What does it do? As "WMIC OS GET LocalDateTime" has this format

```
LocalDateTime
20150223064808.538000+060
```

i am assuming it somehow limits the sting. But how?

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of things going on in that line.

`^` is batch's escape character. It's there so that the next character won't break the for loop.
`|` is a pipe, and it sends the output of the command on its left to the command on its right.
`FINDSTR` searches for a string and returns any that it finds.

Here's where it gets a little complicated:
`\` is findstr's escape character, and allows the next character to be interpreted literally.
`.` is just a period, but without the preceeding `\`, it's a single-character wildcard (f.re would pick up fare and fire, etc.)

`wmic os get localdatetime` runs `wmic` and returns the local date and time, and its output looks like this:

```
LocalDateTime
20150223010540.071000-300
```

When you pipe it to findstr and tell findstr to return lines that contain a single period, you get

```
20150223010540.071000-300
```

And then the whole thing is inside a `for /F` loop so that the output of that command can be stored in a variable.